# two column table layout

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm creating an e-mail template to send out but for some reason, I am unable to create two simple columns in the footer area.

---

**Layout:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<table style="margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; font: normal 10.5px; color: #777777; width: 100%; height: 100%;" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="content" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFFFFF; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba; width: 600px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; background: #1F1F1F;" bgcolor="#1F1F1F">
                            <td style="width: 100%;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                <h1 style="padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; color: #FFFFFF;">Test</h1>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;" align="right">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px;">test</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px;">test</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4 style="color: #27ccc0; text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;">&nbsp;</h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>test</td>
                            <td>test</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

How do I modify the above code to create two simple columns in the footer area, that is still within the e-mail's container?

Comment: you do have two columns in footer... what do you really want here?

Comment: Hi there gp.  Please refer to the image to see how the current layout places the text outside of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make simple structure of html,

1. Don't make table in table. You can use rowspan. [HTML `<th>` rowspan Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_rowspan.asp)
2. cells in thead tag, recommend to use th tag [HTML `<thead>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp)
3. Don't use this style `display:inline-block;` on tr tag
4. Put `color` style on tr tag if cells doesn't have different color

   ```
   <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <table class="content" style="background: none; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba; width: 600px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <thead>
       <tr style="width: 100%; background: #1F1F1F;color: #FFFFFF;">
           <th style="width: 100%;" align="left" valign="middle" rowspan=2>
                <h1 style="padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;">test</h1>
           </th>
           <th style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px" align="right">
               test
           </th>
       </tr>
       <tr style="width: 100%; background: #1F1F1F;color: #ffffff; ">
           <th style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none; text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px" align="right">
               test
           </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td style="background: red;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td style="background: red;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td style="background: red;" colspan="2">
                <h4 style="color: #27ccc0; text-align: center; padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;">&nbsp;</h4>

           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td style="background: red;" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
       <tr style="width: 100%; background: #1F1F1F; color: #ffffff;">
           <td>test</td>
           <td>test</td>
       </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
   </div>
   ```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/y44qL/1/)

Comment: Hi there anonymousxxx, thank you for the quick response.  Kindly view the following jsfiddle, where the body's content doesn't extend to the full width of the container now (highlighted in red) - http://jsfiddle.net/P4sF4/

Comment: use colspan attribute on td tag.. see updated answer

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you very much anonymousxxx.

Comment: damn, i hate laying out emails... :-/ – check [http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/](http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/) out... it can save you a lot of time!